# javascript jquery verification logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a logic question today. I have a form based on .load, which is working just fine. What I'm a bit stuck on is loading a title based on the position of a loaded form area. 
My "next" button works fine because i have verification for each area i load. for example

```
$('#next').click(function()
{
    if(question_pos==0)
    {
        question_pos+=1;
        $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title1");
        showContent(question_pos,"right");
        return true;
    }
});
```

Now what I need is the back button to load the right title based on the position. 
Here is my back button,

```
$('#back').click(function()
{
    if(question_pos>=2 && question_pos<=25)
    {
        question_pos-=1;
        showContent(question_pos,"left");
        return true;
    }
});
```

I need title 1 to be loaded from area pos 1-2, title 2 from area pos 3-7, title 4 from area pos 4-6, and so on. All I need is an example of how to add in the title load to back function.
In case confusion arizes, the

```
if(question_pos>=2 && question_pos<=25)
{
```

Is there only to prevent the back button from changing the pos before pos 2 and afer pos 25.

```
/*New edit*/
```

What about adding a callback? something like

```
$('#back').click(function(){
        if(question_pos>=2 && question_pos<=2){
        question_pos-=1;
        showContent(question_pos,"left");
                   ('#back').callback(function(){
   if(question_pos<=1 && question_pos>=2){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title1");
 }else if (question_pos<=3 && question_pos>=7){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title2");
 }else if (question_pos<=8 && question_pos>=10){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title4");
 }else if (question_pos<=11 && question_pos>=12){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title4");
 }else if (question_pos==13 || question_pos<=16){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title4");
 }else if (question_pos==17 || question_pos<=19){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title4");
 }else if (question_pos==20 || question_pos<=21){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title4");
 }else if (question_pos==22 || question_pos<=25){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title4");
 }

            }
});
```

Maybe something that allows a bunch of extra if statements, or somethins that allows an

Comment: edited to make more sense.

Comment: another edit, maybe a callback to add more if statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(question_pos==1 || question_pos==2){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title1");
 }else if (question_pos==3 || question_pos==7){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title2");
 }else if (question_pos==4 || question_pos==6){
   $("#title_area").load("bl_forms.jsp #area_title4");
 }
```

Comment: This is something ill try when I get back to work on Monday, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
var areas = [
    { start: 1, end: 2, page: '#area_title1' },
    { start: 3, end: 7, page: '#area_title2' },
    { start: 4, end: 6, page: '#area_title4' }
    // and so on...
];

for ( var i = 0, l = areas.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    var area = areas[i];
    if ( question_post >= area.start || question_post <= area.end ) {
        $('#title_area').load( 'bl_forms.jsp ' + area.page );
        break;
    }
}
```

In this way, you have to update only your array of pages, while the loop never changes.

Comment: This looks like what I am looking for, ill try this on monday.